# Java While loop not continuing to next statement

Tags: java, while-loop

Sorry, should've added more

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rpg {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    boolean live = true;

    if (live == true){
      System.out.println("DETECTIVE RPG");

      while (true) {                          // << ENTER CHECK
        System.out.print("\n Press Enter...");
        input = keyboard.next();
        if (input.equals(null))
          break;
      }                                       // ENTER CHECK >>

      System.out.print("Past check.");
```

keyboard is what I named the Scanner.

This prints "Press Enter" to the console and makes sure the input box is empty. If they press Enter it should break the While loop and move onto the next statement, right? When I press Enter it shows another input box and never gets to the next print statement.

Comment: Questionable console output...

Comment: Where is the declaration of `input` and `keyboard`?

Comment: Are you sure `keyboard.next()` returns `null` when you hit the `Enter` key and not, say, "^M" or ""?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no token to return yet from the `Scanner` when just "Enter" is hit.  The [`next()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) will block until it can read a token.

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

Switch to [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()).

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.
>
> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present.

It will return the whole line of input.  When the line is empty, it will return an empty string, `""`, not `null`.  Try

```
input = keyboard.nextLine();
if ("".equals(input))
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood the explanation and it fixed my problem.

Comment: Good answer. Helps when the question is more complete, admittedly. &lt;grin/&gt;